# Simular conexão lenta com WAMP

Tags: php, wamp, localhost

Encontrei [este artigo](http://helpdeskgeek.com/networking/simulate-slow-internet-connection-testing/) que mostra como realizar no próprio navegador (no caso, o Chrome), porém não funciona quando a DevTools está fechada. Existe alguma maneira de fazer isso direto no WAMP para localhost?

Edit 1: Tenho também a intenção de realizar alguns testes em dispositivos móveis, onde até o momento não encontrei tal função como no desktop.

Comment: Você quer que a dev tools fique fechada por te atrapalhar na tela ou tem algum motivo especial?

Comment: Primeiro, porque voce quer uma solução diferente do Dev Tools? Segundo, porque testar no dispositivo móvel se voce consegue pelo proprio Dev Tools simular um dispositivo? Terceiro....você pode usar um sleep() do PHP se quiser testar uma demora de retorno de dados do servidor. Mas eu sinceramente acho que essa solução do Dev Tools é muito adequada para tudo que vc precisa.